# Jest expect.any() not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, preact

So when testing one of my **reducers** in a Preact(not much different to React while testing with JEST) based project, I got bumped into this issue:

Following output comes up when running jest test -

```
● should setup 

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      {"ID": Any<String>, "active": true, "data": Any<Array>}
    Received:
      {"ID": "BysnEuMlm", "active": true, "data": [{"ID": "Hy7wMAz1lm", "code": "dat.fle", "label": "CRES/datum14.cdata", "name": "File", "status": "READY", "value": {"format": "cdata", "name": "datum14.cdata", "path": "CRES"}}, {"ID": "rkB7RMkeX", "code": "prp.kcv", "label": "3 folds", "name": "k-Fold Cross-Validation", "status": "READY", "value": "3"}, {"ID": "ByCmRfygQ", "code": "ats", "label": undefined, "name": " Best First +  Cfs Subset Eval", "status": "READY", "value": {"evaluator": {"name": "CfsSubsetEval"}, "search": {"name": "BestFirst", "options": ["-D", "1", "-N", "5"]}, "use": true}}, {"ID": "HkmVAM1l7", "code": "lrn", "label": undefined, "name": "Naive Bayes", "status": "READY", "value": {"label": "Naive Bayes", "name": "bayes.NaiveBayes", "use": true}}], "output": {"format": "pipeline", "name": "jestReact.cpipe", "path": "/home/rupav/opensource/candis/CRES"}}

    Difference:

    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
    -   "ID": Any<String>,
    +   "ID": "BysnEuMlm",
        "active": true,
    -   "data": Any<Array>,
    +   "data": Array [
    +     Object {
    +       "ID": "Hy7wMAz1lm",
    +       "code": "dat.fle",
    +       "label": "CRES/datum14.cdata",
    +       "name": "File",
    +       "status": "READY",
    +       "value": Object {
    +         "format": "cdata",
    +         "name": "datum14.cdata",
    +         "path": "CRES",
    +       },
    +     },
    +     Object {
    +       "ID": "rkB7RMkeX",
    +       "code": "prp.kcv",
    +       "label": "3 folds",
    +       "name": "k-Fold Cross-Validation",
    +       "status": "READY",
    +       "value": "3",
    +     },
    +     Object {
    +       "ID": "ByCmRfygQ",
    +       "code": "ats",
    +       "label": undefined,
    +       "name": " Best First +  Cfs Subset Eval",
    +       "status": "READY",
    +       "value": Object {
    +         "evaluator": Object {
    +           "name": "CfsSubsetEval",
    +         },
    +         "search": Object {
    +           "name": "BestFirst",
    +           "options": Array [
    +             "-D",
    +             "1",
    +             "-N",
    +             "5",
    +           ],
    +         },
    +         "use": true,
    +       },
    +     },
    +     Object {
    +       "ID": "HkmVAM1l7",
    +       "code": "lrn",
    +       "label": undefined,
    +       "name": "Naive Bayes",
    +       "status": "READY",
    +       "value": Object {
    +         "label": "Naive Bayes",
    +         "name": "bayes.NaiveBayes",
    +         "use": true,
    +       },
    +     },
    +   ],
    +   "output": Object {
    +     "format": "pipeline",
    +     "name": "jestReact.cpipe",
    +     "path": "/home/rupav/opensource/candis/CRES",
    +   },
      }
```

Following is the test case:

```
test('should setup ', () => {
    const state = documentProcessor(
        undefined,
        {
            type: ActionType.Asynchronous.READ_SUCCESS,
            payload: dokuments.active
    })
    // expect(state.active.ID).toEqual(expect.any(String)) - Test case passes iff I run this test with this command only.
    expect(state.active).toEqual({
        data: expect.any(Array),
        active: true,
        ID: expect.any(String),
    })

})
```

Since state gets changed while calling that reducer, I needed to use `expect.any` function, but as per the output, although types are same, test is not getting passed.
Rather in expected its showing up `Any<String>`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`expect.toEqual` checks for equality of `state.active` in your case. To achieve what you want, you have to make multiple `expect` statements:

```
expect(state.active.active).toEqual(true)
expect(state.active.data).toEqual(expect.any(Array))
expect(state.active.ID).toEqual(expect.any(String))
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but what I really want to achieve is basically use `any` for only things which are inevitable to change, here say "ID". Consider this, my Reducer returns a state which is an object say, **Z** =  { ID: 'hdgajs35', X:'fixed_data1', Y: 'fixed_data2' }.
Now with your approach I can only check if ID is of String type. I would never be able to check X,Y, and similarly many other fields in the state object. What I plan to do is this:
expect(state).toEqual({
    ID: expect.any(String),
    ...fixed_state
})

where fixed_state is **Z** but with different ID.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your point. maybe you can add what you want to expect in the test more verbosely or with pseudo-code. Anyhow:  expect(state).toEqual most likely won't be your friend, since this matches object equality which will only pass if you have the very same object. Maybe expect(state).toMatchObject can help you

Comment: tried .toMatchObject, was working great.
But later on, I found that It was fault in my logic.
Now .any is working inside expect().toEqual(). ✨
Thank you so much for your time. Much appreciated.
Happy its working successfully 

Comment: happy to help. does your code from the question work with .toMatchObject instead of .toEqual?

Comment: Yup with .toMatchObject worked, as stated in the docs toMatchObject just matches all the subsets, 
since I had a fault in logic for this test case, I was comparing wrong objects altogether, now I had to dump above code, and make new test case with expect.any for correct logic.

Answer (score 37):

You can use `toMatchObject`:

```
expect(state.active).toMatchObject({
    active: true,
    data: expect.any(Array),
    ID: expect.any(String)
});
```

See more examples in official documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchobjectobject

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this test:

```
test('list', async () => {
  mock.smth.toReturn([anObj], 'aggregate');
  const result = await list(query);
  expect(result[0]).toMatchObject(
    expect.objectContaining({
      ...anObj,
      id: expect.anything(),
    })
  );
});
```

And it failed with this message:

[image]

anObj was:

```
{ event: [], otherProperty: 123 }
```

The problem was in the array. I replaced the [] for 'hi', leaving anObj as:

```
{ event: 'hi', otherProperty: 123 }
```

and it worked!

(I didn't need the array for the test, it was just in an old object)

I think this might be a bug with the jest "toMatchObject" function.